# omnet++ disconnect or turn off the sensor node

Tags: omnet++

We have a network topology. There is a base station, 36 LCN and 1500 sensor nodes. While simulating, I want to turn off / disconnect randomly selected the sensor nodes.I mean ,I dont want to sense any value from this nodes.To do this I used:

```
cModuleType *moduleType = cModuleType::get("SensorNode");
```

`cModule *snIO = modtype->createScheduleInit("snIO", this);`

`snIO->gate("inout")->disconnect();`

sensor numbers are set in the network.ned file
(" Error in module (SensorNode) Network.sn[20] (id=22) at event #5, t=0: NED module type "SensorNode" not found (fully qualified type name expected)").So how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: There is no question in your post. Could you please extend your post to include a question or a description of the problem.

Comment: @floxyz I tried the above code but it Omnet throws an error :("  Error in module (SensorNode) Network.sn[20] (id=22) at event #5, t=0: NED module type "SensorNode" not found (fully qualified type name expected)").So how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I recommend doing the [Tic Toc Tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/) which explains how to correctly use OMNeT++.
In your case you are missing the full name for your module.